# Extracting beginning of occurrence of value to last of occurrence?

Tags: r

I'm trying to compare the first occurence of the first column to the last occurrence. I'm trying to examine how much `col2` changes when the repeated values in `col1` end. So for instance with sample data:

```
Date           col1     col2
2016-12-20       1        5    <= first occurrence of 1    
2017-01-12       1        7    <= last occurrence of 1 (compare 7 > 5, passes: conclude 1)
2017-01-13      -1        8    <= first occurrence of -1      
2017-01-16      -1        10          
2017-01-17      -1        11   <= last occurrence of -1 (compare 11 < 8, fails: conclude 0)
```

If `col1` is 1 and if `last occurrence > first occurrence`, then I want to return a 1. If `col1` is -1 and if `last occurrence < first occurrence`, then I want to return a -1.

```
2016-12-20       1        5     0    
2017-01-12       1        7     1    
2017-01-13      -1        8     0    
2017-01-16      -1        10    0     
2017-01-17      -1        11    0
```

I'm not really sure how to extract the first and last occurrence of a value in the above case. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are the column names in the example?  Which is the first column?  Is it date or the next one?

Comment: Sorry! I had read the above data.frame into an `xts` file. By first column I mean the next one. I'll label them for clarity

Comment: Why 0 for 2016-12-20? As per your explanation the result column should be either 1 or -1.

Comment: @Erdem Akkas Sorry, that was a bit of a shoddy explanation. I only want the `1` or `-1` to take place in the same row as the last occurrence of repeated values in `col2`. In essence, I'm trying to examine how much `col2` changes when the repeated values in `col1` end.

Comment: Why compare 8<11, fails? It is TRUE

Comment: I think it's supposed to be ` 7 > 5` and `11 < 8` , per the question statement. have edited the example to match the same.

Answer (score 0):

considering `df` as your input:

```
df =  read.table(text='Date           col1     col2
2016-12-20       1        5   
2017-01-12       1        7   
2017-01-13      -1        8   
2017-01-16      -1        10          
2017-01-17      -1        11
             ', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

you can try grouping over `col1`, arranging by date, and then simply comparing the extreme values for `col2`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==n()) %>%
  mutate( k = (col2 - lag(col2,1)) * col1) %>%
  mutate( k = if_else((k/abs(k)) <0, 0, k)) %>%
  select(col1, k) %>%
  filter(!is.na(k))
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: col1 [2]

   col1     k
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1
2    -1     0
```

p.s. the output `k` had to be normalized to match your required format.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

`library(data.table)
dt<-setDT(df)
dt[,col4:=ifelse((seq_len(.N)==.N),ifelse((.SD[.N,2]*col1>.SD[1,2]*col1),1,0),0),by=(col1)]`